# Do we lose information when we normalize an image?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, standardization, data-preprocessing, feature-scaling

Before training a machine learning algorithms, it is advisable to perform feature scaling. Suppose we have a "toy" dataset where each image is composed of two pixels $x_0$ and $x_1$. Lets assume that $x_0 \approx 0$ and $x_1 \approx 1$ for all the training samples. Initially, all images will be $(0, 1)$ but after e.g. min-max normalization they become $(1, 1)$, that is we have lost the "contrast".

Are there cases where feature scaling should be perform with caution? Should a per image normalization makes more sense in the aforementioned example?

**How normalization should be performed?**

In case of min-max normalization do we use the min and max values across all pixels of all images? I am asking this because when we have a dataset where columns are features (e.g. height, weight etc) we normalize per column.

Does this per column normalization makes sense in images (if we flatten an $n\times n$ image into a vector with $n^2$ entries)?

Comment: Because standardization in its usual sense will convert $(0,1)$ into $(-1,1),$ yet you claim otherwise, please explain what you mean by "standardization."

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the correction. I wanted to say min-max normalization.

Comment: But min-max normalization leaves $(0,1)$ unchanged, so I still don't understand your question.

Comment: @whuber I am normalizing per column. If I was normalizing based on the maximum (across all pixel positions and all images) and minimum (across all pixel positions and all images) then I will get $(0, 1)$.

Comment: What sense would column-specific normalization make for an image?  In effect that treats the image as a disjoint collection of $n$ columns and thereby loses most information about how the image varies across columns. If this *does* make sense (although I struggle to conceive of any such situation), then of course any constant-value column will remain a constant-value column under any form of standardization and therefore the normalization should create no problems.  In brief, then, you propose a strange procedure and then wonder why it can create strange results *from a different perspective.*

Comment: @whuber That is exactly the reason I am asking if normalization should be performed column wise. Consider the $j$-th image of a dataset, with $x_0^j=10$ and $x_1^j=100$ and $x_0 \in [0, 10]$ and $x_1 \in [0, 100]$. We have contrast since $\frac{x_2^j}{x_1^j} = 10$ but we loose it after normalization since $\frac{x_2^j*}{x_1^j*} = 1$. This procedure looked strange to me when I was reading the [CS231 notes](https://cs231n.github.io/linear-classify/#practical-considerations). Look at the image data preprocessing paragraph, where it says that every pixel can be considered as a feature.

Comment: When someone says "every pixel can be considered as a feature," they must have in mind a collection of many images.  It *can* make sense to standardize them *on a pixel level.*  That's different than what you propose here.

Comment: @whuber I am referring to a dataset (collection of images) in my comment. The upper and lower limit on the intervals are the $\min$ and $\max$ values respectively, for each pixel. The colums that I am referring to are based on a flatten version of an image. E.g. an $8 \times 8$ image can be considered as a vector with 64 entries (features).

Comment: My point is that the situation in your comment and the situation you have been writing about in your post are different.  That makes it difficult for any reader to determine what you're actually trying to do or what the problem might be.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure why in your example standardisation would result in both pixels being 0.

Generally speaking you standardize the values of an image per channel. So in an colored image you would have three 2D Tensors each representing a color (Red, Green and Blue). You would calculate the mean and standard deviation across all images in the training set. Which are then used to standardize/normalize the values of each channel.

In you example, a black and white image, you only have a single channel. Thus, this per channel standardization does not come into play.

As a counter example to yours, I would bring up the MinMax Scaler which scales all values between 0 and 1 your images would look identical to the pre-scaling image.

Lastly, in most cases per image scaling is not advisable, because it distorts the relationship between the images. Lets say you have an image that is almost completely black and only has small pixel value variation that are too small to be picked up by the human eye. Scaling this image on its own, would suddenly make these small differences as meaning full as the much larger pixel value differences in "regular" images.